# Application pool stops SharePoint 2016

Tags: iis, 2016

In SharePoint 2016 development server where I have installed Visual Studi 2016, when I open Central Administration or any other Sharepoint web application  the application pool is stopped every time .

In Event viewer I saw below error:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18340, time stamp: 0x57366075
Exception code: 0xc06d007e
Fault offset: 0x0000000000008a5c
Faulting process id: 0x1500
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2041692449b7d
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: d008fcbc-7009-11e6-80d5-00505696dba2
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: timer service not started when i start it throws message Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" error message when you stop or pause a managed Windows service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check this :
this is MS TechNet
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/92949e23-d6e8-46da-98d9-6f00c0bbb485/event-id8306-securitytokenserviceapplicationsecuritytokensvcactas-is-unavailable-http-error?forum=sharepointadmin

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51723.sp2016-application-pool-issue.aspx